# Make OS-dependent Requires section in an RPM spec file

Tags: rhel, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

### Situation

I have an RPM that uses `semanage` (SELinux policy management tool) and `restorecon` (SELinux context configuration tool) in the post-installation and pre-uninstallation stages.

Unfortunately, between RHEL 6/7 and 8, the package containing these tools was renamed from `policycoreutils-python` to `policycoreutils-python-utils`.

A working spec file for the RHEL8 RPM contains:

```
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python-utils
Requires(preun): policycoreutils-python-utils
```

And a working spec file for the RHEL6/7 RPM contains:

```
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python
Requires(preun): policycoreutils-python
```

### What I try to achieve

I *could* live with the two spec files/two RPMs, one for every OS type, but I'm lazy and I want one spec that serves all.

### What I tried

I read about the OS conditional `%{rhel}`, containing the OS version. The following *should* work, according to the RPM manual:

```
%if %{rhel} < 8
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python
Requires(preun): policycoreutils-python
%endif 

%if %{rhel} == 8
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python-utils
Requires(preun): policycoreutils-python-utils
%endif
```

If I check the value of the `%{rhel}` variable on my target systems, I get what I expect:

```
centos7-system» rpm --eval '%{rhel}'
7

centos8-system» rpm --eval '%{rhel}'
8
```

Installation of this RPM on a CentOS 6/7 instance works fine. However, upon installation of the OS-independent RPM on an CentOS 8 instance, I get:

```bsh
centos8-system» dnf install my-1.26-0.x86_64.rpm
<...>
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides policycoreutils-python needed by my-1.26-0.x86_64
```

Debug output:

```bsh
centos8-system» rpm -ivvvh my-1.26-0.x86_64.rpm 2>&1 | grep Requires
D:  Requires: /bin/bash                                     YES (db files)
D:  Requires: /bin/sh                                       YES (db files)
D:  Requires: /bin/sh                                       YES (cached)
D:  Requires: /bin/sh                                       YES (cached)
D:  Requires: /usr/bin/env                                  YES (db files)
D:  Requires: /usr/bin/perl                                 YES (db files)
D:  Requires: /usr/bin/php                                  YES (db files)
D:  Requires: nagios-plugins                                NO
D:  Requires: perl(Getopt::Long)                            YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: perl(strict)                                  YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: policycoreutils-python                        NO
D:  Requires: policycoreutils-python                        NO  (cached)
D:  Requires: policycoreutils-python                        NO
D:  Requires: rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1        YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1                YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1       YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1                  YES (rpmlib provides)
```

It would seem that the `Requires` for the CentOS 6/7 scenario are used, and not those from the CentOS 8 scenario.

What am I not seeing here? Is there anything I can do to debug this?

### Related and sources

- [How can I specify OS-conditional build requirements in an RPM spec file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/how-can-i-specify-os-conditional-build-requirements-in-an-rpm-spec-file)
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/packaging_and_distributing_software/advanced-topics#rpm-conditionals-examples_rpm-conditionals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could omit the conditionals and depend on the semanage exectutable instead of the policycoreutils-python package:

```
Requires(post): %{_sbindir}/semanage
Requires(post): %{_sbindir}/restorecon
```

See Fedora's [dokuwiki.spec](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/dokuwiki/blob/f217d81d297c29ff165dad47bba4eb1bb3e65c8d/f/dokuwiki.spec) for an example. An example that depends on the packages is [bdii.spec](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/bdii/blob/e55770ecf43636237a036f0726d1a1d3790abecf/f/bdii.spec).

Comment: Right. This way the OS determines which package to pull in dynamically from the binary name. Brilliant! Thanks very much. Accepted and +1.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional in SPEC file are evaluating during **build** time. So when you SPEC file contains:

```
%if %{rhel} < 8
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python
%endif 

%if %{rhel} == 8
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python-utils
%endif
```

and you build your package on RHEL 7 then it will have

```
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python
```

and this Requires will be used even if you install your package on RHEL 8. It will not be re-evaluated after the package was built.

If you want to have only one binary package then you need the file base requires as pointed out by Andreas. The enterprise solution is to use

```
Release: 1%{?dist}
...
%if %{rhel} < 8
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python
Requires(preun): policycoreutils-python
%endif 

%if %{rhel} == 8
Requires(post): policycoreutils-python-utils
Requires(preun): policycoreutils-python-utils
%endif
```

and build it for different platforms using:

```
mock -r epel-7-x86_64 my.src.rpm
mock -r epel-8-x86_64 my.src.rpm
```

the first command produces `my-1.0-1.el7` and requires `policycoreutils-python` While the second one produces `my-1.0-1.el8` and requires `policycoreutils-python-utils`.

As a side note the condition should be written as:

```
%if 0%{?rhel} < 8
```

to prevent syntax error when the macro is not defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!